# Text string into data frame in R

Tags: r, string, text

So I have the following text string:

"ADNOT (Philippe) sénateur (Aube) NI"

And I want to change it into a data frame like the following:

```
LastName   FirstName   District    Party
   Adnot    Philippe       Aube       NI
```

So far I have tried:

```
read.table(text = headings_text, col.names = c("LN","FN","S","D","P"))
```

Which gets me:

```
     LN         FN        S      D  P
1 ADNOT (Philippe) sénateur (Aube) NI
```

But this isn't a data frame and I know I can't reliable turn each word into a column since some district or names may have 2 components.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give us a little more information.  Is this a text file that you are reading in?  If so, what separates the fields - tabs or spaces?  Are fields with spaces always in parenthesis?

Comment: I scraped the information from a local html file. And not necessarily; many of the fields with spaces come in the proposed party column.

Comment: It'd be far more easier to assist if you provide some examples of the variations in your txt file.

Comment: You might also add a "web-scraping" tag to this - I'm not an expert at that, but that tag (if appropriate) might attract more attention from people who are more familiar with these issues.